# SQL Splitting strings by delimiters

Tags: sql

I have a column in a SQL table which contains strings in the format of:

```
Provider - Category: General: Entry (1)
```

I would like to create a SQL statement that splits that into 4 columns giving a result like this:

```
Column1  | Column2  | Column3        | Column4
----------------------------------------------
Provider | Category | General: Entry | 1
```

It would need to be split by `-`, then by the first `:` and I guess then by `(` and lastly remove the `)`

How to go about creating something like that?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Are the data always the same? Or they can change? If the punctuation may change or not.

Comment: using SQL 2012 and I just noticed that sometimes the data might have another set of parentheses in `General: Entry (HD) (1)`

Answer (score 2):

If the data have the same structure, this query should work:

```
DECLARE @TEXT VARCHAR(255) = 'Provider - Category: General: Entry (1)';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@TEXT,1,CHARINDEX('-',@TEXT)-1) AS COL1
,SUBSTRING(@TEXT,CHARINDEX('-',@TEXT)+2,CHARINDEX(':',@text)- 2 - CHARINDEX('-',@text))  AS COL2
,SUBSTRING(@TEXT,CHARINDEX(':',@TEXT)+2,CHARINDEX('(',@TEXT)- 2 - CHARINDEX(':',@TEXT)) AS COL3
,SUBSTRING(@TEXT,CHARINDEX('(',@TEXT)+1,CHARINDEX(')',@TEXT)- 1 - CHARINDEX('(',@TEXT)) AS COL4
```

Output:

```
Col1        Col2        Col3             Col4
Provider    Category    General: Entry      1
```

Edit based on comment:

```
DECLARE @TEXT VARCHAR(255) = 'Provider - Category: General: Entry (HD) (1)';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@TEXT,1,CHARINDEX('-',@TEXT)-1) AS COL1
,SUBSTRING(@TEXT,CHARINDEX('-',@TEXT)+2,CHARINDEX(':',@text)- 2 - CHARINDEX('-',@text))  AS COL2
,SUBSTRING(@TEXT,CHARINDEX(':',@TEXT)+2,CHARINDEX('(',@TEXT)- 2 - CHARINDEX(':',@TEXT)) AS COL3
--,SUBSTRING(@TEXT,CHARINDEX('(',@TEXT)+1,CHARINDEX(')',@TEXT)- 1 - CHARINDEX('(',@TEXT)) AS COL4
,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@TEXT),2,CHARINDEX('(',(REVERSE(@TEXT))) - CHARINDEX(')',REVERSE(@TEXT))-1)) as COL4
```

With this it does not matter whether you have `'Provider - Category: General: Entry (HD) (1)'` OR `'Provider - Category: General: Entry (HD) (1)'`, the output is anyway:

```
Col1        Col2        Col3             Col4
Provider    Category    General: Entry      1
```

The only thing it does not contain the `(HD)`. BUT, you can combine both solutions with `@TEXT NOT LIKE '%HD%'` and `@TEXT LIKE '%HD%'` and then use UNION ALL as workaround.

Comment: Looks good once they are the same but for something like `Provider - Category: General: Entry (HD) (1)` which happens sometimes, will put HD instead of 1 in the last column, where Column3 should be `General: Entry (HD)`. Is there a way to change the last substring to lastIndexOf"("?

Comment: See updated answer. How important is that "(HD)"? I think these queries can provide you with basic approach how to achieve the task.